# What happens to the supernumerary requests when a Django app gets flooded?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a web app using Django. The app has a maximum capacity of `N` RPS, while the client sends `M` RPS, where `M>N`. In other words, the app receives more requests than it can handle, and the number of unprocessed requests will grow linearly over time (after `t` sec, the number of requests that are waiting to be processed is `(M-N) * t`)

I would like to know what will happen to these requests. Will they accumulate in memory until the memory is full? Will they get "canceled" after some conditions are met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer to your question directly without details about your configuration. Moreover for a extremely high usage of your app it's realy hard to determine what will happen there. But surely, you can't be sure that all those request will be handled correctly.

If you are able to count how many requests per second your application can handle and you want to make it reliable for more than `N` requests, then maybe it's a good start to think of some kind of load balancer, which will spread your request over multiple server machines.

To answer your question, I can of think of few posibilities when request can't be handled correclty:

1. Client cancelled he's request (maybe a browser, which can have maximum time execution limit).
2. Time execution of request was above the `timeout` limit set in web server configuration (because of lack of resources, too many I/O operations, ...).
3. Maybe other service (like some blocked PostgreSQL query or maybe Memcache server failed to work) was timeouted
4. Your server machine is overloaded and TCP connection can't be established.
5. Web server of your choice is able to handle only specified in configuration amount of requests/queue length and rejects those over limit (in Apache for example this configuration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listenbacklog).

Try to read something about C10K problem, could be useful to think about it more deeply.